# Using D3DImage in C++ .net

Tags: c++, wpf, directx

I think this is an easy question, sorry I am not really familiar with C++.
I am using D3DImage in C++.Net project which is using it's SetBackBuffer method, and I am also using DX Surface. I don't know how to convert IDirect3DSurface9 to IntPtr as parameter in SetBackBuffer method. Anyone knows? please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ with the IDirect3DSurface9, the surface is a pointer.  For example:

```
IDirect3DSurface9 * pSurface;
/* ... */
IntPtr backBuffer = IntPtr(pSurface);
```

I would also suggest using SlimDX as it is a thin .NET layer on top of D3D.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've never tried managed and unmanaged C++ together.. it is really that simple  (geez). also about the SlimDX I'll consider using it in this project cause I still don't know about the performance yet. 

Thank you.